# max-height set to child's height

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper div and a very tall child in it. The wrapper have `resize: vertical;` so you can extend it.

I want `resize: vertical` to work unless the height of the child is bigger than wrapper. So I need to prohibit extending wrapper adding redundant space.

Is there a pure CSS solution of this problem? It is not a restriction ofcourse.

I guess this can be achieved via `max-height` property in wrapper. But what value shoud I write there?

In the example below you can extend the wrapper with no limitations.

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;margin:0;border:0;
  height: 1000px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}

.wrapper {
  background: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 100%; /* What should be here? */
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child">
    <p>Garpike. Roosterfish bigmouth buffalo sand lance redside lyretail scissor-tail rasbora riffle dace. Mosquitofish golden dojo chub: pineconefish; squawfish hillstream loach, neon tetra tommy ruff clownfish, zebra lionfish snipe eel. Hamlet, "smalleye squaretail perch wolf-eel, snailfish velvet-belly shark Black tetra cherry salmon collared dogfish." Upside-down catfish sweeper wels catfish driftwood catfish nurse shark Arctic char yellowhead jawfish crucian carp, mojarra Sacramento splittail thornyhead antenna codlet banded killifish. Bamboo shark porcupinefish threadfin bream, largemouth bass. Channel bass slender mola plownose chimaera, catalufa paradise fish African glass catfish weasel shark clingfish wolf-eel scissor-tail rasbora Blobfish? Barb, tonguefish featherfin knifefish.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't think it can be done only with CSS and be dynamic also

Answer (score 0):

What about setting the `max-height` to the parent element and then, in your element `max-height: inherit;` - that should work.

Comment: There is a `max-height` in the parent element. Setting `max-height` to child element is not working.